# ITASK API for Windows Scheduler

Tags: c++

Does anybody know what permissions are needed to create ITASK?

This is the error I am getting in C++:

Error creating ITask. Error: -2147024891

Comment: What OS? From MSDN: Note  By default, only a member of the Administrators, Backup Operators, or Server Operators group can create tasks on Windows Server 2003. A member of the Administrators group may change the security descriptor of the Windows\Task folder to let others create tasks.

Comment: The O/S is Windows 2008 and I tried adding everyone to that folder and still same problem.

Comment: Without some code it's hard to tell what's going wrong.. have you looked at this example? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446829(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is 0x80070005 in hex.  Facility 7 = Windows, error code 5 = Access Denied.  The user account used to run this code doesn't have sufficient rights.  Creating scheduled tasks is a privileged operation.  Talk to the server admin about getting the rights to do this.

Comment: Do you know what privilege is needed for this?

Comment: I am trying to ask the admin, but he has no idea what member to add to the account trying to create the task.

Comment: A good place to ask is the home of admin questions: serverfault.com